# What is the difference between Source[T, _] and Source[T, NotUsed]?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, covariance, existential-type

I have an application which is built on top of the Play/Lagom stack. I need to call a service which requires `Source[T, NotUsed]` to stream a file to it. This is the interface of the service:

```
def foo(fooId: UUID): ServiceCall[Source[ByteString, NotUsed], Source[String, NotUsed]]
```

I am therefore using `Accumulator.source` from the Play documentation, in the following way:

```
  private def doSomething(fooId: UUID): BodyParser[Future[Seq[String]]] = BodyParser { _ =>
    Accumulator.source[ByteString]
      .mapFuture { source: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =>
        externalService
          .foo(fooId)
          .invoke(source)
          .map { x =>
            Right(x.runWith(Sink.seq[String]))
          }
      }
  }
```

Now, inside the `mapFuture` call, `source`'s type is `Source[ByteString, _]`, but if I change it to `Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` in order to call the service, as in the example above, I'm getting an error in the IDE that 
`Source[ByteString, _]` is expected. Isn't `_` supposed to mean that I can change the type to whatever I want to, including `NotUsed`? On the other hand, shouldn't these two be semantically equivalent anyway? I found out that the Akka team introduced `akka.NotUsed` to replace `Unit` for when materialized values don't matter in some previous versions, but that still doesn't give me a clue on how to solve my problem.

The above snippet is similar to this example in the [Play documentation on directing the body elsewhere.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Directing-the-body-elsewhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On the other hand, shouldn't these two be semantically equivalent
>   anyway?

No. They are not equivalent because one is a subtype of another but not vice versa.

`Source[ByteString, NotUsed]` is a subtype of `Source[ByteString, _]`. And because `Source` is covariant `Source[ByteString, _]` is the same as `Source[ByteString, Any]`.

```
implicitly[Source[ByteString, NotUsed] <:< Source[ByteString, _]]
implicitly[Source[ByteString, _] =:= Source[ByteString, Any]]
implicitly[Source[ByteString, Any] =:= Source[ByteString, _]]
```

`Accumulator.source[ByteString]` [has type](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/Accumulator.scala#L282) `Accumulator[ByteString, Source[ByteString, _]]`. `.mapFuture(..)` [accepts](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/core/play-streams/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/streams/Accumulator.scala#L41) `Source[ByteString, _] => Future[B]`. And since `X => Y` is covariant in `Y` but contravariant in `X` `Source[ByteString, _] => Future[B]` is a subtype of `Source[ByteString, NotUsed] => Future[B])`

```
implicitly[(Source[ByteString, _] => Future[B]) <:< (Source[ByteString, NotUsed] => Future[B])]
```

So you can use `Source[ByteString, _] => Future[B]` instead of `Source[ByteString, NotUsed] => Future[B]` but not vice versa.

(`B` seems to be `Future[Either[Result, Future[Seq[String]]]]`.)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html